# Is there a method to model one-to-one relationships using ONLY one-to-many relationships?

Tags: salesforce, relationship, one-to-one

I have three objects: a product, a product package, and a packaged product (alliteration apologies). I need to find a way to model the relationship between these objects but I'm doing it on the Salesforce cloud platform, and they only have one-to-many.

One record of type product can be referenced by as many records of type product package as the user wants, and I don't want this. I want one product to have one product package.

The model needs to follow these rules:

- A product is a buyable thing.
- A product package is a collection of products that are shipped as one product.
- A packaged product is a product that is included in a product package.
- ONE product can have ONE product package consisting of ONE to N other products.

Everytime I think of a solution I either forget it before I can write it down or do a bit of work only to realise that it won't work that way.

It's confusing the hell out of me. And I'm running out of coffee.

Comment: I think the key is here:
ONE product can have ONE product package consisting of ONE to N other products.
You should create a Master detail relationship on Product pointing to Product Package, and validate on a trigger that the package does not have the same product more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link below. 
If you have any doubts do comment.

http://one-to-one-salesforce.blogspot.in/

The idea here is to use a combination of rollup summary with validation to impose one-to-one relationship.